# Двойное действие для onClick

Tags: html

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть страница, на ней налеплена форма и несколько кнопок. Кнопки выглядят примерно так:

```
<a class="ttf02" name="p31k01" onClick="document.form.z13.value = '01'">01</a>
<a class="ttf02" name="p31k02" onClick="document.form.z13.value = '02'">02</a>
...
<a class="ttf02" name="p31k50" onClick="document.form.z13.value = '50'">50</a>
```

Собственно можно догадаться, что при нажатии в input у которого name="z13" значение заменяется на название ссылки. Можно ли каким-то образом при нажатии 1 раз вносить данные в инпут, 2 раз удалять, при этом чтобы значений было несколько? Что-то вроде:

```
// жмем ссылку 03, 02, 15
<input name="z13" value"03 02 15 ">
// нажимаем еще раз ссылку 02
<input name="z13" value"03 15 ">
// нажимаем ссылку 05, 07, 15
<input name="z13" value"03 05 07 ">
```

Что-то аналогичное видел на JS и JQ, вот интересует можно ли обойтись без них. Еще как вариант рассматриваю "мьсье знает толк в извращении" вариант: рядом с каждой ссылкой невидимый input name="a01,a02...a50", в котором появляется или исчезает значение, а в input name="z13" отображаются только те, которые не "" (пусто).

Comment: в смысле без JS? вы JS'ом устанавливаете значение:    

    onClick="document.form.z13.value = '01'"

Comment: Сейчас напишу скрипт, момент!

Comment: эм... немного ошибся с формулировкой. без JS в смысле решения увиденные в интернете еле еле помещаются в оперативную память. против чего то простого на JS ничего не имею

Comment: регулярка для поиска и replace для замены текста, ума не приложу что здесь может объемного в плане памяти...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<a class="ttf02" href="#" name="p31k01" onClick="return setV('01');">01</a>
<a class="ttf02" href="#" name="p31k02" onClick="return setV('02');">02</a>
<a class="ttf02" href="#" name="p31k50" onClick="return setV('50');">50</a>
<br/>
<form>
<input name="z13" value="">
</form>
```

скрипт:

```
var setV = function(v) {
    var values = document.forms[0].z13.value.split(' ');
    var idx = values.indexOf(v);
    if (idx >= 0) {
        values.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        values.push(v);
    }
    document.forms[0].z13.value = values.join(' ');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: можно и проще, пробуем сами...

Comment: гениально! спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("lnks");
    var input = document.getElementById("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        div.childNodes[i].onclick = function()
        {
            if(input.value == '')
            {
                input.value += this.innerHTML + ',';
            }
            else
            {
                var arr = input.value.split(',');

                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    if(arr[i] == this.innerHTML)
                    {
                        var stop = true;
                        input.value = input.value.replace(this.innerHTML + ',', '');
                    }
                }

                if(stop != true)
                {
                    input.value += this.innerHTML + ',';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lnks">
    <a>01</a>
    <a>02</a>
    <a>03</a>
    <a>07</a>
    <a>15</a>
</div>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" readonly="true" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: решение классное, даже запись упрощается. (к сожалению "accept" в теме уже влепил, а 2 ставить нельзя)

Comment: @mixalef ничего страшного! Пользуйтесь =)

Answer (score 0):

при клике на ссылку считываете текущее значение и дописываете к нему новое

```
var val = document.form.z13.value
document.form.z13.value = val+' 02'
```

а перед этим должна быть проверка с регулярным варажением - есть ли такое значение внутри строки, если есть, то вместо добавления его просто стираем.

Answer (score -1):

<a href="#d" onclick="document.form.z13"><input type="button" onclick="document.form.z14"></a>

Comment: не минусуйте новичка, жалко как-то

Comment: а кто минусует?